# How to target maven executions to the build folder only?

Tags: node.js, maven, gruntjs, war, bower

I have a project using Maven and the frontend-maven-plugin (com.github.eirslett).

As I run `mvn install` all the executions from the plugin run, and they create a `node_modules`, `bower_components`, and `node` folders in the `src/main/webapp` root, where the actual frontend code is.

The thing is, I wanted to `mvn install` only execute and create those in `war` the package generated in the `build` directory, not in the versioned application code, just like it does with Java libraries.

Is there a way to achieve that?

This is the relevant part of my `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <directory>build</directory>
    <outputDirectory>build/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>WEB-INF/weblogic.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.20</version>

            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>src/main/webapp</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v0.10.34</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>2.1.11</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>bower install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bower</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>grunt build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>grunt</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You are not alone with this. There is an open issue https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/issues/18 with a pull request waiting to be accepted. https://github.com/cfmobile/frontend-maven-plugin/commit/52b7b28d1b8fd449f63ced3d0ed792fde22c041b

Comment: Ticket is [closed](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/issues/18#ref-commit-c6a01c1) witn [<installDirectory> configuration parameter](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/pull/234)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's possible to use <[installDirectory](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/pull/234)> configuration parameter to choose where to install NodeJS.

`frontend-maven-plugin` will install `node_modules` in the place where it founds `package.json`. That's why you need to provide copy of your web resources **with** `package.json` to some `target/<sub-path>`.

Then `frontend-maven-plugin` may be configured by this way:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.24</version>

            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v0.11.14</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>2.13.4</npmVersion>
                <installDirectory>target/<sub-path></installDirectory>
                <workingDirectory>target/<sub-path></workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
            ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The plugin (frontend-maven-plugin) mostly supports this. The "workingDirectory" parameter tells plugin where to do the work (i.e. npm install). That requires though that the build files (i.e. package.json, gruntFile.js) be in that workingDirectory. To accomodate this I added a antrun execution to copy those files over (with filtering) before the rest of the build. My grunt file then references the files from source when appropriate and any output goes in my target-grunt folder.

Here is my config:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>target-grunt</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               ...
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-grunt</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <!-- copy, filter, rename -->
                            <filter token="moduleName" value="${moduleName}" />
                            <filter token="project.version" value="${project.version}" />
                            <filter token="project.artifactId" value="${project.artifactId}" />
                            <copy file="${basedir}/target-grunt/imported-js/main/js/com/verisk/underwriting/config/grunt/npm-package-module/0.0.1/npm-package-module-0.0.1.js" tofile="${basedir}/target-grunt/package.json" filtering="true" failonerror="true" verbose="true" />
                            <copy file="${basedir}/Gruntfile.js" tofile="${basedir}/target-grunt/Gruntfile.js" failonerror="true" verbose="true" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible way in order to do not dirty the frontend resources dir, contained as example in `src/main/frontendResources`, coming from GIT (or another source repo) with the node_modules, bower_components, ..., directories and files generated during npm, bower and grunt execution is:

1. using `maven-resources-plugin`, copy the sources directory `src/main/frontendResources`
   in `/target/webappStagingDir` subfolder during
   initialization phase
2. set the `workingDirectory` and
   `installDirectory` in `frontend-maven-plugin` to `/target/webappStagingDir`
3. set the bower output directory as
   subfolder of `/target/webappStagingDir`. 
    In example put

   {"directory":
       "bower_components"}

   in .bowerrc file
4. after bower build, using
   `maven-resources-plugin`, copy the output built sources contained in
   bower_components folder to `/target/${artifactId}-${version}` during
   prepare-package phase (before war building)

Here is the pom slice:

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>

    <configuration>
        <workingDirectory>${basedir}/target/frontendResourcesStagingDir</workingDirectory>
        <installDirectory>${basedir}/target/frontendResourcesStagingDir</installDirectory>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v8.12.0</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>6.4.1</npmVersion>
            </configuration>
        </execution>        
        <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>bower install</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>bower</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>grunt build</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>grunt</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>build</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <!-- 
            Copy of the /frontendResources directory, coming from GIT, in /target directory
            executed before the compiling and build of frontend resources
            That dir will be the working directory of npm, bower, grunt
            in order to avoid the creation of the direcotries node, node_modules, bower_components, ...
            (they may be committed in repository)
        -->
        <execution>
            <id>copy-frontendResources-toStagingDir-beforeBuild</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/frontendResourcesStagingDir</outputDirectory>
                <resources>          
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/frontendResources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>              
            </configuration>            
        </execution>
        <!-- 
            Copy of the /frontendResourcesStagingDir/grunt_output directory in /target/ directory
            executed after build of frontend resources and before the war pachage creation
            it contains the output of grunt install execution
        -->
        <execution>
            <id>copy-frontendResources-afterBuild</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/${artifactId}-${version}</outputDirectory>
                <resources>          
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/target/frontendResourcesStagingDir/grunt_output</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>              
            </configuration>            
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

This solution is useful also for mixed projects with frontend in Node.js and backend in Java that has a single .war file as output deliverable